# Parse XML file. How to save into database

Tags: java, xml, spring

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<sdnList>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>1</uid>
    <lastName>AAAAAAAA</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
      <program>UID</program>
    </programList>
    <akaList>
      <aka>
        <uid>12</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>      
        <lastName>ABCD</lastName>
      </aka>
    </akaList>
    <addressList>
      <address>
        <uid>25</uid>
        <city>City</city>
        <country>Country</country>
      </address>
    </addressList>
  </sdnEntry>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>2</uid>
    <lastName>BBBBBB</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
      <program>UID</program>
    </programList>
    <akaList>
      <aka>
        <uid>219</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>BCC</lastName>
      </aka>
      <aka>
        <uid>220</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>strong</category>
        <lastName>ABABAB</lastName>
      </aka>
    </akaList>
    <addressList>
      <address>
        <uid>199</uid>
        <address1>Address</address1>
        <city>City</city>
        <postalCode>CODE</postalCode>
        <country>Country</country>
      </address>
      <address>
        <uid>200</uid>
        <address1>Address</address1>
        <city>City</city>
        <postalCode>CODE</postalCode>
        <country>Country</country>
      </address>
      <address>
        <uid>201</uid>
        <address1>Address</address1>
        <city>City</city>
        <postalCode>CODE</postalCode>
        <country>Country</country>
      </address>
    </addressList>
  </sdnEntry>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>3</uid>
    <lastName>CCCCCCC</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
      <program>UID</program>
    </programList>
    <addressList>
      <address>
        <uid>247</uid>
        <address1>Address</address1>
        <city>City</city>
        <country>Country</country>
      </address>
    </addressList>
  </sdnEntry>
</sdnList>
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UploadURLServiceImpl implements UploadURLService {

    @Autowired
    private final FileDTORepository fileDTORepository;

    @Autowired
    public UploadURLServiceImpl(FileDTORepository fileDTORepository) {
        this.fileDTORepository = fileDTORepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean uploadData(String url) {
        try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("sdn.xml"))) {
            byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void parseSdnFile(String fileName) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException{

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

      // try {
           // dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = db.parse(new File(fileName));

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            //Element docEl = doc.getDocumentElement();

            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("sdnEntry");

            List<SdnEntryDTO> ofacs = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node node = list.item(temp);

                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element element = (Element) node;

                            String id = element.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent();
                            String uid = element.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent();
                            String lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent();
                            String firstName = "";
                            if ((element.getElementsByTagName("firstName") != null)
                                    && (element.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0) != null)) {
                                firstName = element.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent();
                            }
                            String program = element.getElementsByTagName("program").item(0).getTextContent();
                            String sdnType = element.getElementsByTagName("sdnType").item(0).getTextContent();

                            //--------------alias

                        List<String> akaList = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (element.getElementsByTagName("akaList") != null && element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").getLength() > 0
                                && ((Element) element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0)).getElementsByTagName("aka") != null) {
                            Node c = element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0);
                            NodeList akaNodeList = ((Element) c).getElementsByTagName("aka");

                            if (akaNodeList != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < akaNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                                    Node akaNode = akaNodeList.item(i);
                                    if (akaNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                        Element aka = (Element) akaNode;

                                        if (aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName") != null && aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName").getLength() > 0) {
                                            akaList.add(aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
                                        }

                                        if (aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName") != null && aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName").getLength() > 0) {
                                            akaList.add(aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (akaList.size() > 0) {

                            SdnEntryDTO sdnEntryDTO = new SdnEntryDTO(Long.parseLong(uid),
                                    firstName + " " + lastName, program, sdnType, Collections.singletonList(String.join(",", akaList)));

                            ofacs.add(sdnEntryDTO);
                        }
                        }
                    }

                for (SdnEntryDTO sdnEntryDTO : ofacs) {
                    fileDTORepository.saveAll(ofacs);
                }
//        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class SdnEntryDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ofac_id")
    private Long uid;

    @Column(name = "fullName", length = 255)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "program", length = 50)
    private String program;

    @Column(name = "type", length = 50)
    private String sdnType;

    @Column(name = "alias", length = 255)
    private List<String> akaList;

    public SdnEntryDTO() {
    }

    public SdnEntryDTO(Long uid, String fullName, String program, String sdnType, List<String> akaList) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.program = program;
        this.sdnType = sdnType;
        this.akaList = akaList;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(Long uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public String getSdnType() {
        return sdnType;
    }

    public void setSdnType(String sdnType) {
        this.sdnType = sdnType;
    }

    public List<String> getAkaList() {
        return akaList;
    }

    public void setAkaList(List<String> akaList) {
        this.akaList = akaList;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface FileDTORepository extends JpaRepository<SdnEntryDTO, Long> {
}
```

I have an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
> java.util.List, at table: customer, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(alias)]

any ideas?

Comment: I will rephrase my question. The output should be:
uid: some data
fullName: some data
program: some data
sdnType: some data
alias: lastName and fullName from akaList should be here

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that it is clearer what you are looking for? Thanks.

Comment: I would like to display the following data: fullName = (firstName + lastName), uid, program, sdnType and alias = (fistName + lastName, belonging to the akaList tag)

Comment: if i add code like this:                                                                                                                  if ((element.getElementsByTagName("akaList") != null)                                                         
               && (element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0) != null)) {                       
           System.out.println("alias : " + element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0).getTextContent()));                               
             } else { System.out.println("alias : " + " ");}

Comment: I have:                                                                                                                                        uid : 1           fullName : AAAAAAAA          program : UID         sdnType : Entity           alias :         12            a.k.a.            ABCD

Comment: I don't need "12" and "a.k.a" in alias, I need only "ABCD"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following for loop instead of yours should do the job, but I totally do not suggest you do so. This is code that is very hard to read. Please consider using other XML parsing libraries, such as JAXB (https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml-libraries).

```java
for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node node = list.item(temp);
    System.out.println("");

    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;

        System.out.println("uid : " + element.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent());
        if ((element.getElementsByTagName("firstName") != null)
                && (element.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0) != null)) {
            System.out.println("fullName : " + (element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent())
                    + " " + (element.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("fullName : " + element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
        System.out.println("program : " + element.getElementsByTagName("program").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("sdnType : " + element.getElementsByTagName("sdnType").item(0).getTextContent());

        List<String> akaList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (element.getElementsByTagName("akaList") != null && element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").getLength() > 0
                && ((Element) element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0)).getElementsByTagName("aka") != null) {
            Node c = element.getElementsByTagName("akaList").item(0);
            NodeList akaNodeList = ((Element) c).getElementsByTagName("aka");

            if (akaNodeList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < akaNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node akaNode = akaNodeList.item(i);
                    if (akaNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element aka = (Element) akaNode;

                        if (aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName") != null && aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName").getLength() > 0) {
                            akaList.add(aka.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
                        }

                        if (aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName") != null && aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName").getLength() > 0) {
                            akaList.add(aka.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (akaList.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("alias : " + String.join(",", akaList));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 06/09/2021**

Use `@ElementCollection` instead of `@Column(name = "alias", length = 255)`. You are defining it as a `List`, so `@Column` does not work since Hibernate does not know what to do with the `List`. `@ElementCollection` does just that by handling a collection of instances of a basic type or embeddable class. Check [this](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/elementcollection-vs-onetomany-in-hibernate-7fb7d2ac00ea) article for more details.

---

**Update 07/09/2021**

Conversion of `List<String>` to a single column in the Database can be achieved as follows:

```java
@Column(name = "alias", length = 255)
@Convert(converter = ListToStringConverter.class)
private List<String> akaList;
```

Now you need to implement `ListToStringConverter` as follows:

```java
@Converter
public class ListToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String>{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : StringUtils.join(attribute,",");
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbData))
            return Collections.emptyList();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(dbData.split(","))) {
            return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: outputs the error of these parts of the code:  element.getElementsByTagName("akaList")./getElementsByTagName/("aka"),     if (/getElementsByTagName/("firstName") != null) {

Comment: and this: NodeList akaNodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("akaList")./getElementsByTagName/("aka");

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it is ok, please check it ;)

Comment: Theonly thingis that when I insert this piece ofcode into my application, I get an error: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org / springframework / boot / autoconfigure / orm / jpa / HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column (alias)]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this?)

Comment: I have entity where: @Column(name = "alias", length = 255)
    private List<String> akaList;

Comment: Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: To answer that, I would need a lot more information regarding your entities and how you are saving them. The piece of code that you shared will work just fine with the for loop I added to my question. If then you use this in any other way, I can't really tell what might be wrong without additional code.

Comment: Please, tell me, how to add code here? I want to show you...

Comment: @
João Dias   Please look, I edited the post

Comment: I followed your advice and added the following to the Entity: ElementCollection
    CollectionTable (name = "alias", joinColumns = JoinColumn (name = "uid"))
    Column (name = "alias", length = 2914)
    private List <String> alias;

Now Hibernate creates two tables for me. But I only need one. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: But how do you expect to map a List to a single column in your table? That is simply not possible. Unless you are ok with concatenating the List of Strings into a single String using an `AttributeConverter`.

Comment: Good. Then maybe it is possible to combine these created tables into one? Through Join?

Comment: The point is, so that the client can work with only one table ...

Comment: You mean "created string into one" not "tables" right? But why is there the requirement of only one table?

Comment: I mean, I would like to see a table with data like this:                id  |  uid_id   |    full_name  | program  | type  | alias

Comment: Ok, understood, but how do you expect the alias column to fit a List of Strings? The only solution is concatenating it into a single String. Is this ok?

Comment: Do you mean one column?

Comment: Yes, you can't simply map a List of String to a single column without transforming the List into a single String.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include this conversion.

Comment: if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbData))            error .isBlank

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;` You need to add Apache Commons Lang to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: It all worked! Thank you very much for your time! You are the best!

Comment: Awesome! Then don't forget to accept the answer as correct so that your question can be "closed" and others can understand easily what a solution might be. Thanks!