# Error creating bean. Could not determine type for: java.util.List

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

In an Entity class, I have a field as: `@Column(name = "alias", length = 255) private List<String> akaList;`

When it's run, I have an error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(alias)]
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: It’s a raw type. So hibernate can’t work out what you want in your list. Add a type.

Comment: What do you mean?) Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to save this List <> to the database. Like this: repository.saveAll ()

Comment: What objects does your `akaList` hold? Strings, or something other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061255/parse-xml-file-how-to-get-child-elements/69065843?noredirect=1#comment122069137_69065843

Comment: Please edit your question here and post your `Customer` entity that has this `akaList`

Comment: @pleft   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061255/parse-xml-file-how-to-save-into-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following annotation: `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` in addition to `@Column`. Usually you address this kind of relationships with `@OneToMany` association. The element collection might seem easier to use than an entity with `@OneToMany` association. But it has one major drawback: The elements of the collection have no id and Hibernate can’t address them individually.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "alias", length = 255) 
private List<String> akaList;
```

Comment: please edit your question and post the full stacktrace of the error, not in comments.

Comment: I added, Hibernate, started saving, but at the end, an error came out:   could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement

Comment: add stacktrace?

Comment: yes the logs from your error, do not post them in comments rather than edit your question and place them there (formatted as code). It is more readable. Concerning your error you do understand that your column can hold only 255 characters, so if your list of strings is greater in total than 255 characters you might get the error you mention.

Comment: Try changing `length = 255` to something bigger e.g. `length = 4096`. Please understand that you cannot save a very big list this way, you will eventually hit the length limit sooner or later

Comment: i added value 10000 characters. Now it doesn't stop. Writes and writes ...
And I checked in pgAdmin. It doesn't create the alias column

Comment: I have 9500 entries in the xml file. It writes down half. The alias column is not created

Comment: I'm desperate. I've been trying to solve this problem for three days

Comment: "It writes down half. The alias column is not created" Sorry I dont understand what you are writing. Do not try  with thousands of entries, try with much less at first check that it works or not and then try with thousands.  Please try to be specific and give proof and examples of your statements.

Comment: If the "alias" column is not created then how it has saved the half of the entries as per your above comment?

Comment: The minimum value at which the program starts is 2914. But it does not stop. I cannot understand why

Comment: Why is the alias column not created, it is registered in my Entity

Comment: @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "alias", length = 2914)
    private List<String> akaList;

Comment: I figured out what was the reason. The project is up and running. But when using the ElementCollection annotation, Hibernate creates not one, but four tables.)