# SaveAll method in Spring application

Tags: java, xml, spring, postgresql

Can List  be in Entity and written as: @Column (name = "someName", length = 50)
private List  someList;
And so that the data of this List <> is written to the created column. I don't understand how to implement this?
Can this be explained with an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error creating bean. Could not determine type for: java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069529/error-creating-bean-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list)

Comment: this my question. I'm already desperate. I can't solve this problem for three days

Comment: Are you using hibernate? You probably need another table to store the values for that list and define one to many relationship.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. If you want to not create another table to hold your list and if your list has basic elements, you can take a look on @ElementCollection, provided in JPA 2.0. Maybe read the answers to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.